# Ember.js RestAdapter - how to connect to external APIs

Tags: ember.js

How can I use ember.js's RestAdapter to connect to external APIs (not on the domain of my server)?

1. Connect to multiple external APIs one by one, and
2. After getting the JSON responses, select only subsets of the JSON objects/attributes and transform them into a standard model (defined in my ember.js app)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Ember Data.

You will have a very difficult time making multiple calls to different endpoints for a single model and then creating the model.  I'd recommend using raw ajax, then sideloading the data into the store.

Here's the notes on side loading for Ember Data

````
  /**
    Push some raw data into the store.

    The data will be automatically deserialized using the
    serializer for the `type` param.

    This method can be used both to push in brand new
    records, as well as to update existing records.

    You can push in more than one type of object at once.
    All objects should be in the format expected by the
    serializer.

    ```js
    App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer;

    var pushData = {
      posts: [
        {id: 1, post_title: "Great post", comment_ids: [2]}
      ],
      comments: [
        {id: 2, comment_body: "Insightful comment"}
      ]
    }

    store.pushPayload('post', pushData);
    ```

    @method pushPayload
    @param {String} type
    @param {Object} payload
  */
````